# How to resolve Autolayout issues after updating to Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, size-classes

I have designed user interface in storyboard in Xcode 7 its working fine when i updated Xcode 8.1 and opened the storyboard the result is below.

[image]

I don't know what apple actually doing with this, When ever new update came i struggling on this kind of issue. Can some one guide me how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @MarcoPace see the layout its messed up. it was fine in Xcode 7.

Comment: Can you show the errors in autolayout by tapping the red arrow icon?

Answer (score 2):

Click on the red button that shows the problems, and see what's wrong, and fix them. Very often you just fix the frames of your views. And then you tap on the various device sizes and check if your layout works with every size.

Comment: We can't possibly know whether future Xcode releases will require the same adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

They did make changes with new xcode 8.0, but I believe its easier then ever.

The concept is same behind only few changes.

Like before you need to do update frames, but now they make it easy so you can view a live preview of your layout without going into preview in show assistant editor.

Just click on device button and it automatically updates frames and shows you your layout.

For more information see: [A Beginner’s Guide to Auto Layout with Xcode 8](https://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/)

Comment: if its so then they have to develop Xcode to adopt previous version design and constrain right ?

Comment: no its already adopted the new  version have very changes even if you do good control over previous version you may not fell more change here

Comment: if  you need  some suggestion or help i can have skype session  with you